# Threading e-mails using In-Reply-To

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send e-mails which an e-mail client will collect together under the same thread.

I am trying to do this using the In-Reply-To header, or the References header.

This is how I add them:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($header, $messageId) {
    $headers =  $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $header);
    $headers->addTextHeader('References', $messageId);
    $headers->addTextHeader('In-Reply-To', $messageId);
});
```

The headers are showing in my mail:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
References: 8def8ad2ba46673db3886aaef3bb230f@swift.generated
In-Reply-To: 8def8ad2ba46673db3886aaef3bb230f@swift.generated
```

but the messages are in separate threads (in Gmail).

Any ideas?

Mick

Comment: What mail client are you testing this in? Some mail clients (e.g. GMail) try to be "clever" and combine messages into "conversations" based on subject line and some kind of heuristics, rather than obeying the mail headers.

Comment: I'm using gmail.

Comment: Right, then assuming "use a real mail client" isn't an option, the question you need to research is "How does GMail define conversations?"

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Why did you edit the code to label it as "javascript"? This is a PHP question, and the code was correctly syntax highlighted as PHP.

Comment: @IMSoP sorry, my bad!

Comment: A quick search turned up a few existing questions that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22639839/157957 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/965/206031 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/16675/206031

Comment: It looks like it works, when I change the format to be <8def8ad2ba46673db3886aaef3bb230f@swift.generated>